# Primefaces hello world

Tags: maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to integrate primefaces into my application, thus I'm following [the primefaces user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf). I don't have any dependencies issue, but when getting to the first example of the guide I'm not getting anything but a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"><head id="j_idt2"></head><body>
    <p:editor></p:editor></body>
</html>
```

According to the guide I was expecting to get a rich text editor, but instead nothing is shown. Below my html code. Can you see any mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:editor />
</h:body>
</html>
```

P.E.: I've added as well primefaces and myfaces as dependencies [to my pom.xml](https://dpaste.de/rnTJ):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The configuration in web.xml seems good as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you add primefaces jar to classpath or pom? Show your web.xml

Comment: Try with simple PrimeFaces component like `<p:inputText />`.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: yes, I have primefaces and myfaces into my pom.xml

Comment: @Omar same result :-(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"><head id="j_idt2"></head><body>
    <p:editor></p:editor>
    <p:inputText></p:inputText></body>
</html>

Comment: Is your application a WAR file? If so, is primefaces.jar in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @fonkap : I don't have primefaces.jar in web-inf/lib, as I'm using maven. I'm not experienced in maven neither, is really necessary to add the jar?

Comment: @fonkap : I've added primefaces-5.1.jar to web-inf/lib, and then got the error "javax.servlet.ServletException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-bootstrap" library". Commenting out the theme selection in web.xml did the trick here. How can I make work the bootstrap theme then? Thanks dude :-)

Comment: I'm not sure as I haven't used Primefaces. I think you have to put "theme.css" in the classpath. Where is this file in your project? Putting it in `java/main/resources` may work or maybe in `WEB-INF`. If I find some time I'll try to build an example.

Comment: @fonkap : it seems they have a bunch of styles ready for download at their site http://www.primefaces.org/themes. Adding the dependency to pom.xml doesn't work, just downloading the bootstrap.jar into web-inf/lib works out... quite weird to me :-)

Comment: Which kind of dependency are you adding to pom.xml? Are you using `maven-war-plugin`, isn't it? Maven should add the dependencies to WEB-INF lib... see this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65047/discussion-between-sogeking-and-fonkap).

Comment: I've answered you in the chat!

Answer (score 0):

According to bootstrap theme need bootstrap.jar, so you pom.xml should be

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>  
        <version>1.0.10</version>  
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but that doesn't solve the main issue here: why primefaces and bootstrap style aren't working if I don't manually add those jars into web-inf/lib

Comment: @sogeking Each theme is packaged as a jar file,
download the theme you want to use, add it to the classpath of your application and then define
primefaces.THEME context parameter at your deployment descriptor (web.xml) with the theme
name as the value. Please read http://primefaces.org/themes.

Comment: thanks, I had already got there. But I can't understand why do I need those jar files in web-inf/lib when I have them already in pom.xml... anyway, it works :-)

Comment: @sogeking Are you sure your project is created as maven project? Basically, you do not add any jar in your web-inf/lib if you add into your pom.

Comment: Yes, it was created as maven project. All other dependencies are imported from pom.xml without problem

Comment: @sogeking Your proplem is when you compile your project with "mvn install" command your war file did not contain any jar inside web-inf/lib ?

Answer (score 0):

can you added h:form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:editor />
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make much difference. My final doubt here is why I need to add bootstrap.jar and primefaces.jar to web-inf/lib even when I have them already in my pom.xml... :-)